# CodeIgniter 3 Issue - "An Error was encountered. Action you have requested is not allowed."

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have simple login form built using codeigniter 3. Many times when I submit the form i get this error "Action you have requested is not allowed". Most of the times it works but i am trying to find a solution so that it works all the time.

Following is my Login Form:

```
<?php echo form_open('admin/index', ['role' => 'form']); ?>
          <fieldset>
            <legend><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Secure Sign-In</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="username">Username</label>
              <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" />
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
              <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Sign In
            </button>
          </fieldset>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

As i understand from other posts it is most likely a CSRF issue hence i am also sharing the config file values:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'testname';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'cookiename';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();

$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

I am only sharing an example of Login page because this is where i am facing issues. Otherwise i have many other forms in rest of the application and some of them are even submitted using Ajax (I add the hidden input with CSRF token)  but have never faced the problem.

Again, Most of the time it works but i do see this error every once a while.

Comment: Take a look at the generated source code for the page and look for the hidden csrf field. The first part of it looks like: `<input type="hidden" name="testname" value=...` Make sure it's there before the submit. If it is there and you still get the error then some where, some how the csrf hash has changed since the page was loaded.

Comment: @DFriend, Value for hidden input is there. I am using codeigniter form_open method to create a form which by default add the hidden input with CSRF value. Could there be an issue because of setting CSRF regenerate to false in config file ?

Comment: Most people run into difficulty when setting regenerate = true. So, no I don't see any issue there. I noticed the use of form_open but thought you should confirm it is adding the hidden field. Next you need to confirm that it really is a csrf token mismatch happening. If you are setup to debug set a breakpoint in /system/core/Security.php and see for yourself what's happening

Comment: @DFriend, Another thing which i have noticed is that most of the time when I face this issue my login page is inactive for a long time. Example: l loaded login page by browsing to the base url (xyz.abc.in) but i did not enter credentials and attempted login for an hour or two. After an hour if i attempt to login without reloading the page i get this error. I am now under the impression that $config['csrf_expire'] = 7200; could be the one causing the issue since csrf is generated on page load but it expire by the time i submit the form. How can i avoid this ? If this is the cause. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think you have found the problem - the csrf cookie is expiring. Options are 1,) set a longer duration, 2.) don't wait so long to log in :)

Comment: I cannot enforce users to not to wait long before doing a log in. Many times they don't even close the window for hours. I can although increase the duration, But i was looking for a more smarter solution like generate a new csrf every time the sign in button is clicked. Thanks.